# 'this' Keyword is not accessing Intended variable it should. Why?

Tags: java, inheritance, this

I am trying to access child class's variable through parent's method using `this` keyword inside method. but its not printing the child's value when the method was called by child's object. Instead it's printing parent class's value even if that method was called by child's object.

Here is my code:

```
class C {

    int t = 9;
    void disp() {
        // here 'this' shows to which object its referring.
        // It showed me same as System.out.println(b) showed me
        System.out.println(this);
        /*
         But, why this.t is printing 9,
         when this method is called by 'b' reference variable,
         it should print 0, because B class contains instance variable t
         of its own and here this is pointing to the object of B class,
         it shows 9 for 'c' and 1 for 'c1' but y not similarly 0 for 'b'
         as when the method is called by 'b',
         ***this refers to the memory location of b but doesn't prints the value of that object***,
         hows that going on???
        */
        System.out.println(this.t);
    }
}

class B extends C {

    int t = 0;
}

class A {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        C c = new C();
        C c1 = new C();
        B b = new B();
        c1.t = 1;
        System.out.println("Memory location of c-->" + c);
        c.disp(); // here output is 9
        c1.disp(); //here output is 1
        System.out.println("Memory location of b-->" + b);
        b.disp();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
c-->PackageName.C@15db9742
PackageName.C@15db9742
9
PackageName.C@6d06d69c
1
b-->PackageName.B@7852e922
PackageName.B@7852e922
9
```

Comment: You can't override fields, only hide them. That is, any code in the parent that is looking at a field will always access the parent's field, not the child's field.

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you make that as easy as possible; starting with using the "preview" feature to ensure that your source code is formatted in decent, readable way. Besides that; I really dont understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting confused between overriding method concept with shadowing of variable, since dynamic binding will call child class method at run time , but this is not true in case of 'this' reference of variable  it will not overwrite parent variable even if you have same name variable in child.

Comment: The correct term is *hiding* ([JLS §8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)). *Shadowing* ([JLS §6.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)] is when a variable in a tighter scope prevents access to a variable in an outer scope, and does not involve inheritance.

Comment: I understand what your saying here, but it could perhaps be reworded a little bit for readability. I think RealSkeptics comment was a lot easier to understand.

Comment: Thank You :) I Will See Further On It. God Bless